# PL011 write to DR when transmission disabled

Tags: uart, arm, register

The PL011 manual seems to assume that a TXE (transmission) is enabled when the CPU writes to DR:
[image]

It doesn't say what happens if the the transmission was disabled (bit 8 of control register is 0)
[image]

Is it okay for an implementation (like an emulator) to just drop the WRITE_DR when transmission is disabled or transmit the character even when the transmission is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PrimeCell UART (PL011) Technical Reference Manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0183/g/):

> To enable transmission, the TXE bit and UARTEN bit must be set to 1.

This means that if a write to the `DR` register occurs while `TXE` is 0, the serial data transmission will not start.

Comment: thanks. what about dropping the write to DR? is that legal? or must any implementation buffer the character if FIFO is enabled, possibly transmitting it in the future when TXE becomes enabled?

Comment: @AbhishekAnand: You're welcome.  I don't understand your comment.  Do you need me to clarify my answer regarding DR writes while TXE=0?  It seems like you are asking completely new questions.